# Is there any way i can print n lines with n columns where (1,1) is 1 ... (1,n) is n then (2,1) is 2 ... (2, n-1) is n and (2,n) is 1 and goes on;

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int input;
    printf("Enter a number between 1 and 9: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    /* check : input is between 1 and 9*/
    if(input < 0)
    {
        printf("Invalid Input.");
        return -1;
    }
    while((input == 0) || (input > 9))
    {
        printf("Enter a number greater than 0 and smaller than 10: ");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        if(input < 0)
        {
            printf("Invalid Input.");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    int i,j;
    for(i = 1; i <= input; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= input; j++)
        {
            if(j <= input - 1)
            {
                printf("%d * ", j);
            }else { printf("%d", j);}
        }
```

> I tried do j = j + 1  but for loop doesn't recognize it

```
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> I want to output something like this : for ex: n = 4,  Output:

```
1 * 2 * 3 * 4
2 * 3 * 4 * 1
3 * 4 * 1 * 2
4 * 1 * 2 * 3
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: You have to inject spaces to get the output to appear as lined up columns, or tabs, but they aren't reliable. You can do a lot using the size control fields in printf. Instead of `%d` try `%5d`

Comment: It just prints n lines of the same thing 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 *... * n. I want it to print the above output i want it every time it changes line the  to print the number + 1 and goes on . Can u help me ?

Comment: @ScottHunter First of all thanks for your interest. Basically my code takes a number N that someone inputs and prints N lines and N columns. The first line must print from 1 to N then the second line from 2 to N and goes on. My problem is that my code prints each line the same thing 1 to N. Can u help me please it would mean so much.

Answer (score 2):

Let's pretend for a second you want to print the following for n=4:

```
0 1 2 3
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
```

Pretty easy, eh? At any position, we simply print `row+col`.

But we want the numbers to wrap around when they become too large. The key is the modulus aka remainder (`%`) operator. `(row+col) % n` gives us the following:

```
0 1 2 3
1 2 3 0
2 3 0 1
3 0 1 2
```

Finally, we just add one (`(row+col) % n + 1`) to get the desired result:

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 1
3 4 1 2
4 1 2 3
```

Comment: It's almost there. There is a little problem. Can u explain me the equation with the module because when i try to do it with a row or a column it doesn't print the right answer. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: `(i+j-2) % n + 1`, or `(i+j) % n + 1` if you loop from 0..n-1 instead of 1..n